# 1D Discontinuous Galerkin - Lagrange vs Legendre Basis

Tags: finite-element, discontinuous-galerkin

Consider the 1D advection equation in its strong and weak forms

$$\ u_t + a u_x = 0 $$
$$\  \int_{x_{j-0.5}}^{x_{j+0.5}}   w u_t \ dx  - a \int_{x_{j-0.5}}^{x_{j+0.5}} w_x u \ dx + a [w(x)\hat{u}]_{x_{j-0.5}} ^{x_{j+0.5}} = 0  $$

Having introduced the piecewise constant Lagrange polynomials or the first two Legendre Polynomials as our test functions, the system can be written as :

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \int (\phi_1)^2 dx \ \int \phi_1 \phi_2 dx \\ \int \phi_2 \phi_1 dx \ \int (\phi_2)^2 dx  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix}_t  - a \begin{bmatrix} \int (\phi_1)_x \phi_1 dx \ \int (\phi_1)_x \phi_2 dx \\ \int (\phi_2)_x \phi_1 dx \ \int (\phi_2)_x \phi_2 dx  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{bmatrix} + a \begin{bmatrix} \phi_1(x_{j-0.5}) \ \phi_1(x_{j+0.5}) \\ \phi_2(x_{j-0.5}) \ \phi_2(x_{j+0.5})  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} -\hat{u}_{x_{j-0.5}} \\ \hat{u}_{x_{j+0.5}} \end{bmatrix} = 0 $$

When solving through the use of the Lagrange polynomial basis, the values $ u_1 $ and $ u_2 $ that are being solved for are the values of the function $ u(x,t) $ at the nodes.
In the case of the Legendre Polynomials, what are we solving for? What is the physical significance of $ u_1 $ and $ u_2 $ and how do they relate to the function values at the nodes, cell average and flux ?

Comment: are you asking about [nodal vs. modal](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10094/discontinuous-galerkin-nodal-vs-modal-advantages-and-disadvantages) DG? if so, then the [DG book by Hesthaven and Warburton](https://books.google.de/books/about/Nodal_Discontinuous_Galerkin_Methods.html) or [these slides](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/jansh/resources/Publications/Lectures/RMMC08-3.pdf) may be of help to you.

Comment: I think you have to place the nodes depending on which order you use. For instance, if you used 0th order Legendre basis, you would be solving for 1 node placed at the center of the element. I've been looking for an answer to this question since a few weeks now, and I'm not sure this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate, consider the 1D case with linear approximations on the elements, i.e., polynomials of degree 1.
Furthermore, given the formulas you wrote down, I assume that your reference element lies on the $[0, 1]$ interval.

### Lagrange polynomials

You already noted that for the [Lagrange Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) the approximation on the $i$'th element corresponds to esentially interpolating between the nodes, i.e.,
$$u_i(t,x) = \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}(t) l_j(x) \tag{1} \label{1}$$
(here $N=1$) where
$$ l_j(x) := \prod_{m = 0, m \neq j}^N \frac{x - x_m}{x_j - x_m}.\tag{2}$$
To keep the notatin relatively compact, I will suppress the temporal dependency of the $u_{i,j}$ for now.

Clearly, the Lagrange polynomials $l_j(x)$ fulfill a Kronecker property at the interpolation nodes $x_m$ and thus also, the finite element approximation $u_i(x)$ fulfills
$u_i(x_m) = u_{i,m}(t)$ since
$$u_i(x_m) = \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j} l_j(x_m) = \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j} \delta_{jm} = u_{i,m}.\tag{3}$$

I would like to stress that until now, we have not decided where to place the nodes $x_j$! These nodes are in fact usually determined from the choice of the quadrature rule used for approximating the integrals in the weak form.
Typical choices include [Gauss-Lobatto](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LobattoQuadrature.html) or [Gauss-Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_quadrature).
The reason to choose the same nodes $x_m$ for interpolation and quadrature (collocation) becomes appearant when you take a look at the weak formulation
$$ \int_0^1 u_t(t,x) w(x) dx + \int_0^1 a u(t,x)_x w(x) dx = 0 \quad  \forall w \in W^1 \tag{4} \label{4}
$$
where here, it makes sense to choose the [Lagrange polynomials as a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501407/lagrange-basis-functions-as-bases-of-polynomials-space) for the testspace $W^1$.
To get the idea, it suffices to consider the first term in \eqref{4}, for a detailed discussion you can take a look at [this documentation](https://trixi-framework.github.io/Trixi.jl/stable/tutorials/scalar_linear_advection_1d/).
Alright, let's substitute \eqref{1} into $\int_0^1 u_t(t,x) w(x) dx$ and test with the basis of functions $l_k(x)$ of $W^1$:
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}(t)' l_j(x) l_k(x) d x,  &k = 0, 1 \tag{5}\\
\overset{\text{Quadrature of sufficient order}}{=}& \sum_{l=0}^N w_l \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}(t)' l_j(x_l) l_k(x_l)  &k = 0, 1 \tag{6} \\
\overset{\text{Same nodes for interpolation and quadrature}}{=}& \sum_{l=0}^N w_l \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}(t)' \delta_{jl} \delta_{kl}  &k = 0, 1 \tag{7}\\
=& w_k u_{i,k}(t)' &k = 0, 1 \tag{8} \end{align}

Which is a drastic, yet correct simplification of the integration which motivates the use of identical nodes for interpolation and quadrature.

### Legendre Polynomials

Now, let's consider [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials). The first two Legendre polynomials *on interval* $[-1, 1]$ are given by
$P_0(x) = 1, P_1(x) = x$.
From this definition it is clear that the $P_j(x)$ (in particular $P_0(x)$) **can not** fulfill a Kronecker property at *any* choice of nodes.
Instead, the Legendre polynomials are *orthogal with respect to the $L^2$ [scalar product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-InnerProduct.html)*:
$$ \int_{-1}^1 P_i(x) P_j(x) d x = \frac{2}{2k+1} \delta_{ij}.\tag{9}$$
This is a big qualitative difference compared to the Lagrange basis!

Let's map the interval $[0,1]$ onto $[-1, 1]$ through
$$ \xi \mapsto 2\xi -1, [0, 1] \rightarrow [-1, 1] \tag{10}$$
and define the basis functions $\phi_k(x), k = 0,1$ as
$$\phi_k(x) := \sqrt{2k+1} P_k(2x - 1) \tag{11}$$
which posess the Kronecker property
$$\int_0^1 \phi_i(x) \phi_j(x) dx = \delta_{ij}, \tag{12}\label{12}$$
i.e., they form a proper basis of $W^1:=\{w \in L^2([0, 1]) : w \in \mathcal{P}^1\}$ where $\mathcal{P}^p$ denotes the vector space of polynomials of degree $p$.

Again, we expand the approximation $u_i(t, x)$ on the $i$'th interval in these base functions as

$$u_i(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j} \phi_j(x). \tag{13} \label{13}$$
Now, let's consider again the first term in the weak formulation \eqref{4}
and test with the $\phi_l(x)$ (since they form a basis of our test-space $W^1$):
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}' \phi_j(x) \phi_l(x) d x & l = 0, 1 \tag{14}\\
=& \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}' \int_0^1  \phi_j(x) \phi_l(x) d x & l = 0, 1 \tag{15}\\
\overset{\eqref{12}}{=}& \sum_{j=0}^{N} u_{i,j}' \delta_{jl}  & l = 0, 1 \tag{16} \\
=& u_{i,l}' &l = 0, 1 \tag{16}
\end{align}

### Answer

So to finally answer your question, the $u_{i,j}$ can be seen as a weight that quantifies the influence of the $j$'th basis function $\phi_j(x)$ when tested with $u_i(t, x)$. In contrast to Lagrange, the $u_{i,j}$ provide sort of a "global" statement on $u_i$, whereas in the Lagrange case, this requires the integration weights $w_j$.

Values at nodes, interfaces and average can then be simply computed from \eqref{13}.

Comment: That's a nice answer,  however a more concrete answer would be: (1) In case of Legendre polynomials $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the constant and linear contributions to the final solution. (2) $u_1$ is the cell average. (3) There is no simple connection between the modal values and the physical/numerical flux.

Comment: (1) I elaborated that much to show the difference between both approaches. Of course, you could just say that $u_0, u_1$ are the coefficients of the constant and linear part, but that gives about as much information as saying $u_0, u_1$ are the contributions of the first and second Lagrange polynomial. (2) Correct, I might add that to my answer. (3) Well I mean that's what approximate Riemann solvers are for, right? You provide trace values and then they take over the business.

Comment: My intention was merely to complement your very good, detailed answer, especially with regard to the original very specific question. ;)

Comment: I didnt mean to sound that rude, the character limit got me :D